# need advise on using sort command in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

How to sort a file using sort command..

I would like to sort the file based on 2nd field which is seperated by  "," as a delimiter

Ex:
filename1, 465, output_file1,

filename2, 300, output_file2,

Expected output :

filename1, 300, output_file,

filename1, 465, output_file,

I tried this command

```
sort -t, +1 -2 <file.txt>
```

But this didn't help. Please let me know if I am missing something

thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

GNU sort:

```
sort -t, -k2 -n file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use
`sort -t, -nk 2 -s file.txt`

-n specifies it as numeric sort and -k specifies key to be used for sorting
The +1 etc., options are not supported now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-k 2` to specify field 2 should do it:

```
sort -t , -k 2 $file
```

Not sure what `+1 -2` comes from. Also, this should probably be on https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The command below will do it for you, nice and simple :-)

sort -t, -k 2n,2 t.txt